# Cell match and compare

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, excel-2007, vlookup

I have four columns structured like so:

```
Column A: Data title for metric.
Column B: Corresponding metric for data title in Column A.
Example:
    Row 50   |BlahBlah | 5   |
Column C: Same as Column A from above.
Column D: Same as Column B from above.
Example:
    Row 10   |BlahBlah | 10  |
```

What I want to do is make a fifth column, Column `E` , where I first look for the title from Column A in the range of Column C, and if this title exists in the range of Column C then I want to subtract the corresponding metric in Column B from Column D.

So in the example above, I would match Column A, Row 50 with Column C, Row 10 and the entry in Column E would be `5`.

Comment: Are you trying to do this in a Formula or VBA?

Comment: Formula. Where is a similar question?

Comment: @Heplar: pnuts is referring to the 13 answers on your previous 8  questions, and you appear to not have sekected or **accepted** any answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2,C:D,2,0)-VLOOKUP(A2,A:B,2,0),"")
```

copied down to suit.